# Why is python slower inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker

The following small code snippet times how long adding a bunch of numbers takes.

```
import gc
from time import process_time_ns

gc.disable() # disable garbage collection
for func in [
    process_time_ns,
]:
    pre = func()

    s = 0
    for a in range(100000):
        for b in range(100):
            s += b
    print(f"sum: {s}")

    post = func()
    delta_s = (post - pre) / 1e9 # difference in seconds
    print(f"{func}: {delta_s}")
```

To my surprise, this takes much longer when run inside a docker container (~1.6s) than it does when run directly on the host machine (~0.8s).
After some digging, I found that some of docker's security features may cause slowdowns (https://betterprogramming.pub/faster-python-in-docker-d1a71a9b9917, https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-performance-overhead/). Indeed, adding the docker argument `--privileged` reduces it's runtime only ~0.9s.
However, I'm still confused by this ~0.1s gap I'm observing, which doesn't show up in the article.
I've set my cpu frequency to 3000MHz and fixed the python execution to run on core 0.

Statistics of 30 measurements each:

|  | local | docker --privileged | docker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avg | 0.79917586 | 0.904496884 | 1.61980727 |
| std | 0.02433539 | 0.031948695 | 0.04034594 |
| min | 0.78087375 | 0.867265714 | 1.56995282 |
| q1 | 0.78211388 | 0.880717119 | 1.58672566 |
| q2 | 0.79006154 | 0.895180195 | 1.61322376 |
| q3 | 0.80732969 | 0.916945585 | 1.64363027 |
| max | 0.89824817 | 1.012580084 | 1.72252714 |

For measurements, the following commands were used:

- local: `taskset -c 0 python3 main.py`
- docker --privileged: `taskset -c 0 docker run --privileged --rm -w /data -v /home/slammer/Projects/timing-python-inside-docker:/data -it python:3 python main.py`
- docker: `taskset -c 0 docker run  --rm -w /data -v /home/slammer/Projects/timing-python-inside-docker:/data -it python:3 python main.py`

What causes the remaining docker overhead?
Can it be mitigated to achieve bare-metal-performance?

Edit: Measurements were taken on a linux mint 20.3 host (kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-117-generic); docker version: 20.10.17

Comment: Is it the same Python version? There's an expected overhead from containerizing, but this does seem severe. Normally you'd expect 10-25% slower.

Comment: If you need bare-metal perf you should use bare-metal.

Comment: can you test this, in docker image bash shell vs windows/linux shell and provide result

Comment: `taskset -c 0 docker run` You are restricting docker _client_ which connects to docker server and the server starts the command. The taskset of the  process that connects to the docker API has nothing to do with taskset of the processes inside the docker container. Use `docker run --cpuset-cpus 0` and other `docker run --help` options. Or `docker run .... taskset -c 0 python main.py`.

Comment: @tadman Yes, it's the same version (3.10.0). According to the blog posts, there should not be a performance difference with `--privileged`, but I'm observing one (~0.1s, ~11%)

Comment: I think that is assumed, but you didn't say so explicitly: you are on Linux, right? No intermediate VM between the OS and the container, right?

Comment: @jsbueno Correct, I'm on a linux mint host.

Comment: @KamilCuk good point! Alas, after fixing that I'm still observing the same times.

Comment: Are the measurements the same when you move `print(sum)` below `post = func()`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, the tests don't take much time. I'm using the times printed from the script (difference between two `time.process_time_ns()` calls).

Comment: @KamilCuk The `print` doesn't affect timings (in any significance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slowdown seems to be caused not by docker, but by differences in the python binary.

I copied the python packaged within the docker image `python:3` to my host machine (copying docker's `/usr/local` to my hosts `docker-python` folder).
Then I ran the same benchmark again on using this binary with the following command: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=docker-python/local/lib taskset -c 0 docker-python/local/bin/python3.10 main.py`
And voila, the measurements using this "dockerbinary" are the same (within measurement error) as those measured with "docker --privileged":

|  | local | dockerbinary | docker --privileged | docker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| avg | 0.79917586 | 0.89829016 | 0.904496884 | 1.61980727 |
| std | 0.02433539 | 0.03554546 | 0.031948695 | 0.04034594 |
| min | 0.78087375 | 0.86344007 | 0.867265714 | 1.56995282 |
| q1 | 0.78211388 | 0.86950620 | 0.880717119 | 1.58672566 |
| q2 | 0.79006154 | 0.88853465 | 0.895180195 | 1.61322376 |
| q3 | 0.80732969 | 0.91612282 | 0.916945585 | 1.64363027 |
| max | 0.89824817 | 0.99477790 | 1.012580084 | 1.72252714 |

Mystery solved :)

---

Now, what is the difference between these binaries?
As far as I could tell, the binary shipped with docker is `with debug_info, not stripped`, while my local binary was only `stripped`.

```
$ file `which python3.10`
/usr/bin/python3.10: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=fb3f4369481251e6ba441382fd6d9ab47af0db29, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
$ file docker-python/local/bin/python3.10
docker-python/local/bin/python3.10: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=618b23f947f202224f4ea8e16375ac7bcad13c4f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

My guess is that the `with debug_info` compilation introduces this ~11% performance overhead.
If this is correct, it prompts the next question "Why does the default docker image use this binary if it causes such a significant slowdown?".
To that, I have no answer at the moment (also this guess may be entirely wrong).

Crosslink: https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/825

Comment: Same problem here. Is there an easy workaround for this? Different Image?

Comment: @PhilippS. you might find a performance boost by using the `-slim` image, as according to the linked github issue, the slim images' python binary doesn't have debug_info.